# Get Facebook page like count for OpenGraph v2.10

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can't get Facebook to return the page like count, the response provided does not match what the API states. According to the docs, the following URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/<page-id>/likes?access_token=<access-token>&summary=true
```

should return a JSON response with a `summary` key that provides the like count in the corresponding hash. The problem is the response never contains the summary key, but it does contain the `data` and `pager` keys as specified in the docs.

I'm certain my access token is valid and my page ID are correct.

I've also tried to get the `page_fans` metric from the page insights via the following URL, but it simply returns an empty `data` object.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/<page-id>/insights/page_fans?access_token=<access-token>
```

Is there another way to go about retrieving the like count for a page or any particular reason that the requests would succeed, but be missing the relevant data?

Facebook Doc Links:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/object/likes

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/insights

**UPDATE**

I was able to retrieve the count by using this Graph API call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/<page-id>?access_token=<access-token>&fields=engagement
```

As New Hand pointed out, you can get the key directly, without going through the engagement field using the following:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/<page-id>?access_token=<access-token>&fields=fan_count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to get the fan_count?

Please try this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/<page-id>?access_token=<access-token>&fields=fan_count
```

Comment: Yeah, I did. Engagement has that key as well. I'm still interested in why those other calls don't contain the relevant information though, contrary to what the docs state.